# How to mock function calls in mock-turtle?

Tags: c++, boost, mocking, turtle-mock

I have a piece of code implementing a class that I want to test, lets call it A.cpp and the test test_A.cpp.

The A.cpp file uses some functions from a library that commands a particular device, lets call this libdevice.
In particular, the A class offers a method connect() which internally calls send_conf() function, which is defined inside libdevice.  In code:

- A.cpp file

> ```
> #include <libdevice.h>;     
> public class A{
> //private
>      public:
>      bool connect() {
>           int myconf = 3;
>           if(send_conf(myconf) == -1) {
>               return false;
>           }
>           return true;
>       }
> }
> ```

- test_A.cpp

> ```
> extern "C" {
>      MOCK_FUNCTION(send_conf, 1, int(int)); 
> };
>
> BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(connect_test) {
>     bool ret; 
>     A* myA= new A();
>     MOCK_EXPECT(send_conf).once().with(3).returns(-1);
>     ret = myA->connect();
>     BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(ret, false); 
> }
> ```

Now, if I use the related MOCK_FUNCTION() macro from mock-turtle library when I compile my test I receive a linker error:

> A.cpp: undefined reference to 'send_conf'.

This is due to not linking the library, which at this step is not available. How can I achieve a mock for this set-up in mock-turtle?

Comment: What is the signature for `send_conf()` and how do you use `MOCK_FUNCTION()` exactly?

Comment: I added these infos to my original question. The libdevice.so library contains C code, so I used extern "C" to reflect that, it does not work even if i remove the extern "C" keywords

Comment: Are you sure the `send_conf` function doesn’t declare any calling conventions?
See http://turtle.sourceforge.net/turtle/reference.html#turtle.reference.creation.function

Comment: I saw that section, but it does not show any possible calling convention that i should try. Also, i'm using Mingw32 compiler on windows.

Comment: What does the signature for `send_conf` look like, when you look it up in the header file?

Comment: extern "C" {
    int send_conf(int x);
}

Comment: I suppose you could always use a wrapper to redirect e.g. with an `extern "C" { int send_conf(int x) { send_conf_mock(x); }}` and then `MOCK_FUNCTION(send_conf_mock, 1, int(int));`.